# Oracle BI tag missing Oracle

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

I went looking for some potential help on Oracle BI and I did a tag search for Oracle (rational place to start) but I found no tags related to Oracle BI or anything even remotely similar. So I turned to Google and started finding questions on SO about Oracle BI and noted that some of them were tagged with [bi-publisher](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bi-publisher/info). Shouldn't this be something like **oracle-bi-publisher**? There's no synonyms to suggest but I would think this would make the tag easier to find.

Comment: that tag has 79 questions. You could create the tag on one of the questions and then make the two synonyms?

Comment: @rene: no-one has enough score on that tag to suggest a synonym. Completely retagging is an option, but having a mod do the synonymification(?) sounds like a better plan.

Comment: @mat I agree with that...